# Obtain & manipulate bit pattern of float as integer

Tags: python, floating-point, bit-manipulation

In Python 2.5, I have a float and I'd like to obtain and manipulate its bit pattern as an integer.

For example, suppose I have

```
x = 173.3125
```

In IEEE 754 format, `x`'s bit pattern in hexadecimal is `432D5000`.

How can I obtain & manipulate (e.g., perform bitwise operations) on that bit pattern?

Comment: I am not too well versed on this topic, but have you tried the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the string you want (apparently implying a big-endian, 32-bit representation; Python internally uses the native endianity and 64-bits for floats) with the `struct` module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = 173.125
>>> s = struct.pack('>f', x)
>>> ''.join('%2.2x' % ord(c) for c in s)
'432d2000'
```

this doesn't yet let you perform bitwise operations, but you can then use struct again to map the string into an int:

```
>>> i = struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]
>>> print hex(i)
0x432d2000
```

and now you have an `int` which you can use in any sort of bitwise operations (follow the same two steps in reverse if after said operations you need to get a `float` again).

Comment: Thanks to all who provided answers.  I was able to get both techniques (1 using ctypes, and 2 using struct) to work.  What I don't know is which is preferrable.  It appears that using pack & unpack of struct provides a representation-independent solution, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, I was wondering whether there are significant performance differences between the "ctypes" and "struct" solutions.

Comment: @JaysonFix: 1) do you mean platform-independent?  If so, and you are explicit about endianism, I think the answer is yes.  2) Whether there is enough difference to matter to you depends on what you're going to be doing... millions of manipulations?  If so, you should benchmark for yourself so you'll understand the implications, both in terms of performance in in terms of ease of use and maintainability.

Comment: Hi, could you shed light on why you specify '>' for big endian? It works correctly but I am confused on what role endian (big, little) plays...

Comment: In Python 3, switch `ord(c)` for just `c`, since `s` is now a `bytes` object.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that a Python float object might not be a IEEE 754, because it is an object (in fact they are, but internally they could hold whichever representation is more convenient)...

As leo said, you can do a type cast with ctypes, so you are enforcing a particular representation (in this case, single precision):

```
from ctypes import *
x = 173.3125
bits = cast(pointer(c_float(x)), POINTER(c_int32)).contents.value
print hex(bits)
#swap the least significant bit
bits ^= 1
```

And then back:

```
y = cast(pointer(c_int32(bits)), POINTER(c_float)).contents.value
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `struct` or `xdrlib` module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = 173.3125
>>> rep = struct.pack('>f', x)
>>> numeric = struct.unpack('>I', rep)[0]
>>> '%x' %numeric
'432d5000'
```

Now you can work with `numeric`, and then go in the reverse direction to get your floating point number back. You have to use >I (unsigned int) to avoid getting a negative number. `xdrlib` is similar.

References: [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html), [xdrlib](http://docs.python.org/library/xdrlib.html).

Answer (score 4):

For reference, it is also possible to use numpy and view.

```
import numpy

def fextract( f ):
  bits = numpy.asarray( f, dtype=numpy.float64 ).view( numpy.int64 )
  if not bits & 0x7fffffffffffffff: # f == +/-0
    return 0, 0
  sign = numpy.sign(bits)
  exponent = ( (bits>>52) & 0x7ff ) - 1075
  mantissa = 0x10000000000000 | ( bits & 0xfffffffffffff )
  # from here on f == sign * mantissa * 2**exponent
  for shift in 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1:
    if not mantissa & ((1<<shift)-1):
      mantissa >>= shift
      exponent += shift
  return sign * mantissa, exponent

fextract( 1.5 ) # --> 3, -1
```