# Get the "bits" of a float in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, bitwise-operators

I am looking for the Python equivalent of Java's `Float.floatToBits`.

I found this [Python: obtain & manipulate (as integers) bit patterns of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922771/python-obtain-manipulate-as-integers-bit-patterns-of-floats) but does anyone know of a less complicated way?

Comment: Also how would I do the opposite: `Float.BitsToFloat`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer that Alex Martelli gives in that question is really pretty simple -- you can reduce it to:

```
>>> import struct
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def floatToBits(f):
...     s = struct.pack('>f', f)
...     return struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]
...     
... 
>>> floatToBits(173.3125)
1127043072
>>> hex(_)
'0x432d5000'
```

Once you have it as an integer, you can perform any other manipulations you need to.

You can reverse the order of operations to round-trip:

```
>>> def bitsToFloat(b):
...     s = struct.pack('>l', b)
...     return struct.unpack('>f', s)[0]

>>> bitsToFloat(0x432d5000)
173.3125
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the need for enforcing big-endian. Any problem with using '=' instead ?

Comment: Thanks. Also how would I do the opposite: `Float.BitsToFloat`?

Comment: I wouldn't depend on that assertion working too often.  Try it with `startVal = 123.456`.

Comment: Yeah, good point, and I like to yell at people about equality testing on floats. I'll remove it.

Comment: I like it, but is there anything that doesn't involve string conversions? I've often found via profiling that strings are what code takes the most time operating on.

Comment: To be serious/honest, if I was worried about speed here, this is something where I'd drop to C (where the problem is trivial to the point where it basically disappears)

Comment: This answer is WRONG! Check that `2.2250738585072014e-308 == 5e-324` gives `False`, but both are converted to `0` by `floatToBits`.

Comment: Both of those values are out of range for a float (which is the topic of the question), so I'm not sure why you would expect them to work. If you need the additional range and precision of a double, you could write a pair of `doubleToBits()` and `bitsToDouble()`functions.

Comment: For `double` values you need to modify the above code as follows: `s = struct.unpack('>q', struct.pack('>d', f))[0]`, where `l` and `f` were changed to `q` and `d`. If your use case allows you could also use the float.hex() and float.fromhex() methods.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the 64-bit, little endian representation of a python float<sup>1</sup> just to add to the discussion:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import binascii
>>> print('0x' + binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<d', 123.456789)))
0x0b0bee073cdd5e40
```

References:

- [`struct.pack` endianness and byte size format specifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)
- [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify)

---

<sub>[1] for example I needed this specifically for interoperability with .NET's [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on intel (ie little endian)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> f = ctypes.c_float(173.3125)
>>> ctypes.c_int.from_address(ctypes.addressof(f)).value
1127043072
```