# Python: flip a bit in a float

Tags: python, floating-point, bit

I would like to flip a specific bit in a float in Python.
It seems to be quite difficult, because the operand | works only for int.

For now I have tried to convert a float into a int: [Get the "bits" of a float in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431170/get-the-bits-of-a-float-in-python)
But the proposed solution seems not working for too large float.

Comment: _"But the proposed solution seems not working for too large float."_ Please provide an example where that proposed solution doesn't work.

Comment: Right. The trouble comes from my side. The solution is working and let me to: 
`cast(pointer(c_int32(cast(pointer(c_float(x)), POINTER(c_int32)).contents.value ^ 1 << pos)), POINTER(c_float)).contents.value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested about it, the final function is for a double-precision:

```
from struct import *

def bitflip(x,pos):
    fs = pack('d',x)
    bval = list(unpack('BBBBBBBB',fs))
    [q,r] = divmod(pos,8)
    bval[q] ^= 1 << r
    fs = pack('BBBBBBBB', *bval)
    fnew=unpack('d',fs)
    return fnew[0]
```

And for a single-precision:

```
def bitflip(x,pos):
    fs = pack('f',x)
    bval = list(unpack('BBBB',fs))
    [q,r] = divmod(pos,8)
    bval[q] ^= 1 << r
    fs = pack('BBBB', *bval)
    fnew=unpack('f',fs)
    return fnew[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack`. This is tested under Python 3. There may be differences for Python 2, consult the doc.

```
>>> from struct import pack,unpack
>>> fs = pack('f',1.0)               # pack float ('f') into binary string
>>> fs
b'\x00\x00\x80?'

>>> bval = list( unpack('BBBB', fs)) # use list() so mutable list 
>>> bval
[0, 0, 128, 63]
>>> bval[1]=12                # mutate it (byte in middle of mantissa bits)

>>> fs = pack('BBBB', *bval)  # back to a binary string after mutation
>>> fs
b'\x00\x0c\x80?'

>>> fnew=unpack('f',fs)  # and let's look at that slightly altered float value
>>> fnew                 # NB it is a tuple of values, just one in this case
(1.0003662109375,)
```

unpack requires the exact right length of string for the format. If you are working along a buffer you can use `unpack_from( fmt, buffer, offset)` where `offset` defaults to 0 and the requirement is that `buffer` is *at least* long enough.

Comment: You could also unpack into type `i` or `I` to get a single 32-bit integer instead of 4 bytes. In fact it's not necessary to use `unpack` to get bytes at all, you could have just used `bval = list(fs)`.

Comment: Or even `bval = bytearray(fs)`, and then `bval` can be modified in place and there's no need to `pack` the bytes again afterwards: just do `fnew = unpack('f', bval)`.