# Python write 32bit binary float to file

Tags: python, bin

I have a file I made with `open`. I need to write a float to it in binary format. How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: use `struct` module. please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431170/get-the-bits-of-a-float-in-python

Comment: @Selcuk I meant `open`. Also, my original code is `open("file.xyz", "w")`.

Comment: `open('file.xyz','wb').write( struct.pack('f',[3.7]) )` .  You must use a binary file.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. That seems to be what I was missing.