# Python Access the raw bytes of a Float

Tags: python

I have a series of float64's that represent rgb values, and I am trying to interpret this as an image using python. For each float64, bits 0-15 correspond to the data for an uint8 for the red value, bits 16-31 are for green, and 32-47 are for blue. How can I get these integer RGB values?

I know this kind of bit manipulation is very odd to be doing in python, but bear with me. Basically all I need is to interpret the underlying bits of a float as an int instead(not trying to cast). The closest thing I've found that allows me to access the bit values is [python struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), but it doesn't seem to actually do what I want(and I'm sure it's very inefficient).

I've tried to accomplish it with the following code:

```
raw_byte_data = struct.pack('f', float_value)
data_as_int = struct.unpack('i', raw_byte_data)[0]
r = data_as_int & 0xFF
g = data_as_int >> 8 & 0xFF
b = data_as_int >> 16 & 0xFF
```

I'm not sure what this does, but whatever it does it doesn't give me the output bytes I want. Hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do at least.

Comment: What exactly is the source of your data? You *could* use `struct` to do this, but maybe numpy would be more wieldy.

Comment: Also, what you are asking doesn't make sense. `uint8` are *8 bits*, not 16. Do you mean `uint16`? Or am I missing something about the way images are represented?

Comment: So, you probably need something like `r,g,b = struct.unpack_from('HHH', struct.pack('d', 3.14159))` where `'d'` is for doubles  (you want float64 not float32) and you want to unpack 3 unsigned longs (uint16)

Answer (score 0):

After some more fiddling, I was able to get it to work using python struct thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431170/get-the-bits-of-a-float-in-python). See below.

```
def float_to_rgb(f):
    s = struct.pack('>f', f)
    bits = struct.unpack('>l', s)[0]
    r = bits & 0xFF
    g = bits >> 8 & 0xFF
    b = bits >> 16 & 0xFF
    return (r,g,b)
```

I think the key here was unpacking the bytes as a long int('l').

Comment: You said float64, not float32...

Comment: Is your image just a long one pixel height string ?