# How read particular bit position of floating number?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to read particular position of floating number such as x[16:3] (4th-bit to 17th-bit).
Case of C-language is is simple like this

```
bits = x & ((2**L - 1) << M);
```

Case of Python, '&' of mask operation is not allowed for floating point numbers.
Then how to do it on the Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: obtain & manipulate (as integers) bit patterns of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922771/python-obtain-manipulate-as-integers-bit-patterns-of-floats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly, but this would be my solution:

```
import struct

def float_to_bin(num):
    return format(struct.unpack('!I', struct.pack('!f', num))[0], '032b')

x=16.4637159674589415472835945

string=str(x)
bitx=float_to_bin(x)

part_of_string=string[4:17]
part_of_bitx=bitx[4:17]
```

I copied the float_to_bin function once from somewhere else (probably somewhere from Stackoverflow) to make the float a binary number. That function already makes the binary number a string, so then you can just use the usual indexing. If you want to read the particular position of the float number, you can just make that number a string and then use the indexing.

I hope, I got your question right. Best,
lepakk

Comment: Thank you! I understand.

Comment: If it's working, can you please accept the answer and close this question? Thank you.